# Something runs shutdown.exe at Windows XP startup

Tags: windows-xp, boot, shutdown

On a Windows XP system something executes shutdown.exe at Windows XP startup. It is really annoying but I can't prevent it. I started the system in safe mode, and tried to find the responsible service or application but no luck. Is there a way I could find this out?

Comment: Is there a popup? E.g. [`shutdown initiated by NT authority system`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaster_%28computer_worm%29) ?

Comment: If it's a delayed shutdown (`shutdown -s -t [seconds]`), then you can cancel it with `shutdown -a` as a temporary solution.

Comment: As Windows starting, a command line window appears with the title "shutdown.exe". The system doesn't react since first it is too busy with loading processes, then it is too busy with shutting down.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)? It's part of the Microsoft Sysinternals suite. This should show you everything you need to try and diagnose the issue if it is indeed a startup issue. Also, I would not just look for shutdown.exe as a virus scan and malware scan maybe important on this machine too as it sounds not-quite-malicious.

[image: Autoruns Image @ Technet]

Comment: Pretty sure AutoRuns can also be run from WinPE. I think it's included with MSDaRT.